# Export Multi column Excel spreadsheet from Powershell script

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell, csv, output

I have been working at this for what seems like way too long now. I am pulling all of the ADgroups names and descriptions in my domain. At this point it doesn't necessarily matter but its eating at me.

```
$exportList = @()
$ADgroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Description

Foreach ($group in $adgroups){
$GroupObj = New-Object System.Object
$GroupObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $group.Name
$GroupObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Description -Value $group.Description

$exportList += $GroupObj
}
$exportList | Out-File C:\test\ADGroups.csv
```

And the file comes out like this where all of the data is within column A

[image: Excel Spreadsheet test output screenshot]

but I would like for the name to show in column A and the Description to show in column B I have tried making different Arrays and tried calling the properties in different ways but nothing I have tried yet has worked and I am sure that I am missing something very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Out-File` Instead of `Export-CSV` which export a text file instead of a comma separated file

Replace the:

```
$exportList | Out-File C:\test\ADGroups.csv
```

To:

```
$exportList | Export-CSV C:\test\ADGroups.csv
```

Also, You can cut some lines and simply do:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Description | 
Select Name,Description | Export-CSV C:\test\ADGroups.csv
```

Comment: I swear that I did try that at some point but when I just made that small change and nothing else it worked..... Thank you for pointing out my blind spot good sir!